# Memcached not working automatically in a specific docker container

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I'm trying to run a Symfony application in docker and initially I started off with a full `ubuntu` image, but now I want to strip it down to just `php7.4-apache` base image, but I'm having a strange issue with `memcached`. I will try to describe the issue, but first this is my `ubuntu` image:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN  apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php wget git build-essential libxml2-dev zip unzip \
    software-properties-common vim memcached php-zip \
    php-memcached php-curl php-dom php-apcu php-mysql \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

...

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

And this is my `php7.4-apache` image

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# install system packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev libmemcached-dev memcached

# install PECL packages
RUN pecl install pecl/apcu_bc-1.0.3 memcached igbinary msgpack

# install php extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install dom pdo_mysql zip session

# enable php extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-enable memcached apcu igbinary msgpack

# copy the custom php.ini
COPY .docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

# remove cache dirs
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

...

EXPOSE 80
```

This is what my custom `php.ini` looks like:

```
# configure apc
extension=apc.so
apc.enable_cli=1
# configure sessions
session.save_path="/var/lib/php/sessions"
```

So the issue is that the application uses memcached for sessions. And whenever I use `apache7.4-apache`, the application throws the following error:

```
Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler.
```

But this error goes away if I run `service memcached start` manually in the running docker container and the application starts working normally.

But I don't get this error message at all with the `ubuntu` image.

So to narrow things down, I think there is something different about `php-memcached` and `docker-php-ext-install memcached`.

Here are the outputs of `service --status-all` from both containers:

```
php7.4-apache
 [ - ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  memcached
 [ - ]  procps

ubuntu
 [ - ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  memcached
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
```

So how does `ubuntu` use `memcached` without starting the service and why `php7.4-apache` can't do the same?

**UPDATE:**

After some more digging, `php7.4-apache` uses `memcached=1.5.6` whereas `ubuntu` uses `memcached=1.5.22`. I looked at these release notes and I think it might be related:
https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes1518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly doubt that anyone would have the same scenario, but I solved it by just using a separate docker container for `memcached` and connecting my application to that instead.